# an algorithm to store '{' and '}' in two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to make an algorithm.
The inputs may be like the following.

```
- a{1}b{1}c{1}
- a{a{1}b{1}c{1}}
- a{a{a{1}b{1}}b{b{1}c{1}}d{1}}
```

And I am having two arrays named as "ys" and "ns".
I need to store the starting braces '{' in the array "ys" and ending braces '}' in the array "ns". But the challenge is to store the position of the starting and ending braces in the input string to be same corresponding position in the two arrays.
For example,
consider the 2nd input.
The output must be like this.

```
ys[0]=>1, ys[1]=>3, ys[2]=>7, ys[3]=>11.
ns[0]=>14, ns[1]=>5, ns[2]=>9, ns[3]=>13.
```

**My code:**

var lastPoint = line.pathPoints[line.pathPoints.length - 1].anchor; // [x, y]

```
var eqValues = (prompt("Enter something ", "", "")); //getting the values to write
var eqValuesCopy = eqValues;


    var nFlag=0;
    for(var i=0;i<eqValuesCopy.length;i++){
        if(eqValuesCopy[i]=="{"){
            if(i!=0){
                validBCheck=eqValuesCopy[i-1]+eqValuesCopy[i];
                if(validBCheck!="/{"){
                    ys.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        ysLength=ys.length;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<eqValuesCopy.length;i++){
        if(eqValuesCopy[i]=="{"){
            nsLength=ns.length;
            var j=i;
            while(j<eqValuesCopy.length){
                j++;
                if(nsLength<ysLength){
                    if(eqValuesCopy[j]=="}"){
                        ns[nsLength]=j;
                        break;
                    }else if(eqValuesCopy[j]=="{"){
                         nsLength++;
                    }else{

                    }
                }
            /*else{ 
                    for(var k=0;k<=ysLength;k++){
                           // alert(ns[k]);
                        if(ns[k]==undefined){
                            ns[k]=j;
                            //alert(ns[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
```

I am writing this program in javascript inside illustrator.
Only thing is I couldn't make the logic for this algorithm.

Comment: `The output must be like this` what type of javascript object is that?

Comment: @jaromanda X This is the javascript I am using. https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html
The thing is that, I just need the logic in any language. So that, I could change it in my needs ! :)

Comment: no, I mean the "expected output" ... how is that supposed to be represented in javascript?

Comment: Yes, using javascript only. 
Need the out put like this.
ys[0]=>1, ys[1]=>3, ys[2]=>7, ys[3]=>11.
ns[0]=>14, ns[1]=>5, ns[2]=>9, ns[3]=>13.

the position of pair of braces(open and its closing) must be stored in the corresponding position on arrays "ys" and "ns".

Comment: so, a string yeah? or did you mean `ys` would be an array `[1,3,7,11]` and `ns` an array `[14,5,9,13]`

Comment: One way to do this would be to use Regex to find the first matching pair, where a matching pair is defined as "{" followed by only alphanumerics followed by "}". Keep repeating until no more brackets are left

Comment: each corresponding position in the array "ys" and "ns" should have the correct pair of braces. I mean, ys[0] has the position of '{' and ns[0] must  have the position of '}' of the correct pair. Hope you got it. I had changed the code. Please check it! :) @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
    for(var i=0;i<eqValuesCopy.length;i++){
        if(eqValuesCopy[i]=="{"){
            if(i!=0){
                validBCheck=eqValuesCopy[i-1]+eqValuesCopy[i];
                if(validBCheck!="/{"){
                    ys.push(i);
                }
            }
        }
        ysLength=ys.length;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<eqValuesCopy.length;i++){
        nsLength=ns.length;
        if(nsLength<ysLength){
            if(eqValuesCopy[i]=="{"){
                var j=i;
                while(j<eqValuesCopy.length){
                    j++;
                    if(eqValuesCopy[j]=="}"){
                        ns[nsLength]=j;
                        break; 
                    }else if(eqValuesCopy[j]=="{"){ 
                        nsLength++;
                    }else{ 

                    }
                }  
                i=j;
            }
        }
    }
    for(var k=0;k<eqValuesCopy.length;k++){
        if(eqValuesCopy[k]=="}"){
            var h=k;
            while(h<eqValuesCopy.length){
                h++;
                if(eqValuesCopy[h]=="{"){
                    break;
                }else if(eqValuesCopy[h]=="}"){ 
                    nsDummy.push(h);
                    break;
                }else{ 

                }
            }
        }
    }
nsDummy.reverse();
for(var x=0;x<nsLength;x++){
    if(ns[x]===undefined){
        ns[x]=nsDummy[x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution you can refer. Not using more javascript array functions since it will be easy to understand the logic if need to convert to other languages

```js
function parseString(s){
var ys = [];
var id = [];
var k = 0;
var ns = [];
s = s.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
 if (s[i] == '{') {
  ys.push(i);
  id.push(ys.length - 1);
 }
 if (s[i] == '}') {
  ns[id[id.length - 1]] = i;
  id.pop();
 }
}
console.log(ys);
console.log(ns);
}

parseString('a{1}b{1}c{1}');
parseString('a{a{1}b{1}c{1}}');
parseString('a{a{a{1}b{1}}b{b{1}c{1}}d{1}}');
```